# Can we create circular magnetic fields without current carrying wires

Tags: electromagnetism

[image: circular magnetic fields]

Can we create a matrix of ring shaped magnetic fields as shown in the attached picture

Comment: magentic field lines have to close on poles, either north or south.

Comment: @ anna v "magentic field lines have to close on poles, either north or south." Surely you don't *mean* this.

Comment: @PhilipWood except for error in spelling, yes. I do mean it, the plots above are not realiizable.

Comment: I agree that the plots aren't realisable, but I don't understand about magnetic field lines closing on poles. I thought magnetic field lines were continuous loops without ends.

Comment: see this https://openstax.org/books/college-physics/pages/22-3-magnetic-fields-and-magnetic-field-lines . even the answer that describes circular field  lines below  is talking of electron magentic dipoles, (question asks without current carryiing wires)

Comment: @PhilipWood   Is it possible that the two of you have different meanings of the phrase "close on poles"?

Comment: @garyp Thank you. I think something like that must be going on.

Comment: @PhilipWood, the "field lines" surrounding a permanent magnet in an _accurate_ diagram all would be closed loops. But, part of the every loop is _inside_ the body of the magnet. Most of the diagrams you'll find in text books and on web sites omit showing parts of the field lines that are inside the body of the magnet. It makes the diagram look less cluttered—more aesthetically pleasing to the artist who drew it—but unfortunately, it hinders students from understanding what is really going on.

Comment: Yes indeed. But Anna v must surely know this.

Comment: But @annav won't know that we're debating this unless someone tags her name, but I just took care of that.

Comment: @PhilipWood yes, Garyp is correct, I am talking of simple closed loops as around a current carrying wire ( which is the question in the title).In my view loops inside matter go   from di**pole** to dipole  so cannot be like the ones around a current carrying wire..

Answer (score 0):

Those circular field lines are just like the internal field of magnetized core memory
toroids.   So, we can certainly create such a field, but when we do
so, it is with application of electrical current.   The right material
(ferromagnetic) will sustain the field indefinitely thereafter.

The pairing of electron spins creates the field without electricity-in-wires
current.   It is equivalent to currents in the surfaces of the toroid,
however.